# How to get list of spfx extensions available for my SharePoint online tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions

Very happy new year to all. As i am working on modern experience. I was going through the Microsoft road map. there i found that they have rolling out some of new extensions. How can i check that is available for my tenant. 
Is that possible to have a list of extensions i can use for my tenant.
We have Application Customizer, Command Set, and Field Customizer categories.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the SharePoint Framework includes following three extension types.

- Application Customizers
- Field Customizers
- Command Sets

Per my research, there are no other new extension types. Learn more about [SharePoint Framework Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions).

When create a new extension by running the Yeoman SharePoint Generator, it will promote “which type of client-side extension to create”. It lists all extension types you can create.

[image]

I suppose that you are reading [SharePoint Framework roadmap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/roadmap). This is a list of areas that SharePoint engineering has in the backlog and is looking into. This does not mean that all of them will be delivered, but they are looking into getting items and topics from this list gradually released with the future releases of SharePoint Framework.